# How to incorporate two task arrays in one SGE shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell script for use on Sun Grid Engine. I want to be able to incorporate two task arrays into the script. One is a list of file names, the other is numerical (referring to chromosomes 1 to 22). If I were to write this in a loop, I would do (e.g.):

```
readarray -t QTL < QTL_file_list.txt
for i in ${QTL[@]} 
do for j in {1..22} 
do echo '"$i"_"$j"' 
done 
done
```

However, I want to be able to do this as an array. What I have tried is:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe smp 1-8
#$ -l h_vmem=4G
#$ -N extract_QTL_SNPs
#$ -j y
#$ -t 1-22

# read list of QTL files into an array
readarray -t QTL < QTL_file_list.txt

plink2 --dosage chr${SGE_TASK_ID}.out.dosage.gz --map chr${SGE_TASK_ID}.map --extract ${QTL[$SGE_TASK_ID-1]}SNPlist.txt --write-dosage --out ${QTL[$SGE_TASK_ID-1]}chr${SGE_TASK_ID}_tmp
```

Which successfully incorporates every element from the QTL array (e.g. RegionA, RegionB, RegionC, RegionD, RegionE), but only outputs one chromosome element for each QTL element, e.g.

```
RegionA_chr1_tmp
RegionB_chr2_tmp
RegionC_chr3_tmp
RegionD_chr4_tmp
RegionE_chr5_tmp
```

Is there a way of incorporating both arrays into the one script so that 22 files are generated for each QTL element?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is this your whole script? Because you shown code for one instance of `SGE_TASK_ID`. I don't think without a loop it would generate 5 different files

Comment: It is. What happens is there are 14 files getting pointed to using the QTL array. This script appears to run the command once for each of these 14 files (which is what I was trying to put across in the example output). I know it is the ${QTL[$SGE_TASK_ID-1]} part that is messing it up, but I can't figure out how to write this so that I get 22 files (suffix: _chr1_tmp .. _chr22_tmp) for each of the 14 files indexed in ${QTL}. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, to generate 22 files for each region, run two loops, one for the QTL array and one inside for iteration up to 22

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t qtlArray < QTL_file_list.txt
# Assuming qtlArray contains RegionA, RegionB upto E

# Now iterating over the qtlArray, you don't need to loop over 
# indices ${arr[idx]} but just do as

for qtlElement in "${qtlArray[@]}"; do
    for iterator in {1..22}; do
        plink2 --dosage chr"${iterator}".out.dosage.gz \
               --map chr"${iterator}".map \
               --extract "${qtlElement}"SNPlist.txt \
               --write-dosage --out "${qtlElement}"chr"${iterator}"_tmp    
    done
done
```

Comment: I'll need to let it run overnight, but shall return with an upvote once I can confirm that the mystery has been solved! Thanks very much for your help. It's hard to find information on more detailed SGE shell scripting on the internet, so this has been invaluable!

Comment: It definitely does the business! The only thing is I was trying to parallelalize the process (although I realise the way I have phrased the question isn't clear on that front as the example I give is a loop!) So I shall try and do some tweaking to make it so that it runs as different tasks. But thank you :)